# Trying to create a table/list of my EventBrite course listings

Tags: plugins, widgets, events

I have an ever evolving list of courses on EventBrite. I would like to display them in two ways on my website:
- On this page: http://agilepainrelief.com/agile-training-overview/certified-scrummaster-training as a table with Date, Location, Price and perhaps Early bird pricing
- On the blog as feed of the next 5-6 events I have upcoming. In this case I need enough control of the formatting to put my CST seal (a logo of sorts) above the list.
- Added bonus the table is filtered by event type so as I add more training types a table on each page only displays the correct one.

I've got no problem paying for a plugin that can actually do this, but so far can't find one.

Any ideas?

Lost in Wordpress

Comment: Too bad this question was closed. I have exactly the same requirements. Arguably, this is less of a WordPress issue and more of an Eventbrite API issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a custom post type and setting either the post data or some custom meta to the time of the event, then using `WP_Query` to handle the output? If you've got a light php background I can write you sample code that will get you through the basic concept, just let me know.